# How to duplicate a application window in GWT/GXT?

Tags: gwt, gxt

we have a CRM-like application written in GWT/GXT with help of our library which wraps some GXT widgets like ComboBox or Grid from GXT to simplify interaction with relational database. When the application starts a user have to log in and after successfully login the user can see main horizontal menu and some welcome information. If the user want to do something (e. g. to find a customer) he/she has to click somewhere in the menu and a new GXT modal window appears. Now we want to give the user a possibility to open a new session (e. g. to handle a second customer and visually compare customer's data with the first customer) in a new browser window.

How to do it?

Best Regards,
Jacek

Comment: Do you want to open the same application, but with a defined view?

Comment: I want to open the same application skipping of course the login process, because the user is already logged.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know to comunicate between browser tabs is to use HTML 5 localStorage. Here is a good [tutorial](https://truongtx.me/2014/06/16/cross-tab-communication-using-html5-dom-storage/). In GWT you can use [gwt-storage](https://github.com/seanchenxi/gwt-storage) to easily manipulate the localStorage.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've read about it a little bit. But in which form do you suggest to save as SessionStorage? A plain text text for user name/password is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a new Window or browsertab you will need to solve two problems:

1. You will need to specify the session. This can be done by simply create some kind of session token-cookie. This should be flagged with http-only for security reasons). New windows will send the same cookie (and the user is logged in)
2. You need to specify the item, you want to show. This can be done by using the history API and store the token in the URL